# OpacityMask on path Segment

Tags: silverlight, bezier

How to use OpacityMask on the last of point of segment?
It works fine if don't move our path, but if we move you path then the opacity will not affect the last point; its position remains on the where it was last.

#### Sample code

```
<UserControl x:Class="SLTest.Bezier"
         xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
         xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml"
         xmlns:d="http://schemas.microsoft.com/expression/blend/2008"
         xmlns:mc="http://schemas.openxmlformats.org/markup-compatibility/2006"
         Width="500"
         Height="500"
         mc:Ignorable="d">

<Grid x:Name="LayoutRoot" Background="White">
    <Canvas>
        <Ellipse x:Name="PointStart"
                 Canvas.Left="26"
                 Canvas.Top="30"
                 Width="20"
                 Height="20"
                 Cursor="Hand"
                 Fill="DarkGreen" />
        <Ellipse x:Name="PointMiddle"
                 Canvas.Left="200"
                 Canvas.Top="100"
                 Width="20"
                 Height="20"
                 Cursor="Hand"
                 Fill="Black" />
        <Ellipse x:Name="PointEnd"
                 Canvas.Left="406"
                 Canvas.Top="42"
                 Width="20"
                 Height="20"
                 Cursor="Hand"
                 Fill="DarkRed" />
        <Path Canvas.ZIndex="-1"

              StrokeThickness="10" Canvas.Left="28" Canvas.Top="27" UseLayoutRounding="False">
            <Path.Stroke>
                <LinearGradientBrush SpreadMethod="Pad">
                    <GradientStop Offset="0" Color="DarkGreen" />
                    <GradientStop Offset="0.5" Color="Black" />
                    <GradientStop Offset="1" Color="DarkRed" />
                </LinearGradientBrush>
            </Path.Stroke>
            <Path.Data>
                <PathGeometry>
                    <PathFigure x:Name="Path" StartPoint="100,10">
                        <QuadraticBezierSegment x:Name="Segment"
                                                Point1="200,100"
                                                Point2="300,10" />
                    </PathFigure>
                </PathGeometry>
            </Path.Data>
        </Path>
    </Canvas>
</Grid>
```

#### CS Code

```
namespace SLTest
{
    public partial class Bezier : UserControl
    {
        bool isDragging = false;

        public Bezier()
        {
            InitializeComponent();

            AttachEventHandlers(PointStart);
            AttachEventHandlers(PointMiddle);
            AttachEventHandlers(PointEnd);

            // make sure the bezier reflects our gui control points
            UpdateBezier();
        }

        private void AttachEventHandlers(Ellipse point)
        {
            point.MouseLeftButtonDown += new MouseButtonEventHandler(Point_MouseLeftButtonDown);
            point.MouseLeftButtonUp += new MouseButtonEventHandler(Point_MouseLeftButtonUp);
            point.MouseMove += new MouseEventHandler(Point_MouseMove);
        }

        private void UpdateBezier()
        {
            double radius = this.PointStart.Width / 2;

            Path.StartPoint = Offset(GetPoint(PointStart), radius);
            Segment.Point1 = Offset(GetPoint(PointMiddle), radius);
            Segment.Point2 = Offset(GetPoint(PointEnd), radius);

        }

        private Point Offset(Point inpoint, double offset)
        {
            Point point = new Point(inpoint.X + offset, inpoint.Y + offset);

            return point;
        }

        private static Point GetPoint(DependencyObject sobj)
        {
            Point point = new Point((double)sobj.GetValue(Canvas.LeftProperty), (double)sobj.GetValue(Canvas.TopProperty));

            return point;
        }

        void Point_MouseMove(object sender, MouseEventArgs e)
        {
            if (!isDragging)
                return;

            Ellipse point = sender as Ellipse;
            Point newLocation = e.GetPosition(this);

            MoveShape(point, newLocation);

            UpdateBezier();
        }

        private static void MoveShape(DependencyObject shape, Point newLocation)
        {
            shape.SetValue(Canvas.LeftProperty, newLocation.X);
            shape.SetValue(Canvas.TopProperty, newLocation.Y);
        }

        void Point_MouseLeftButtonUp(object sender, MouseButtonEventArgs e)
        {
            if (!isDragging)
                return;

            isDragging = false;
            Ellipse point = sender as Ellipse;
            point.ReleaseMouseCapture();
        }

        void Point_MouseLeftButtonDown(object sender, MouseButtonEventArgs e)
        {
            Ellipse point = sender as Ellipse;
            isDragging = true;
            point.CaptureMouse();
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I am not perfect but may be you get some idea.

try below code.

```
    private void UpdateBezier()
            {

    ......OlD Code

//New Code Added
     double angle = Angle(Path.StartPoint.X, Path.StartPoint.Y, Segment.Point2.X, Segment.Point2.Y);            
                radialtransform.Rotation = angle;


                radialtransform.Rotation = angle;
                if (Math.Abs(angle) < 90)
                {
                    radialtransform.TranslateX = 0.5;
                    radialtransform.TranslateY = 0.5;
                }
                else if (Math.Abs(angle) < 180)
                {
                    radialtransform.TranslateX = -0.5;
                    radialtransform.TranslateY = 0.5;
                }
                else if (Math.Abs(angle) < 270)
                {
                    radialtransform.TranslateX = -0.5;
                    radialtransform.TranslateY = -0.5;
                }
                else
                {
                    radialtransform.TranslateX = 0.5;
                    radialtransform.TranslateY = -0.5;
                }

    }



 public double Angle(double px1, double py1, double px2, double py2)
        {
            // Negate X and Y values
            double pxRes = px2 - px1;
            double pyRes = py2 - py1;
            double angle = 0.0;
            // Calculate the angleror
            if (pxRes == 0.0)
            {
                if (pxRes == 0.0)
                    angle = 0.0;
                else if (pyRes > 0.0) angle = System.Math.PI / 2.0;
                else
                    angle = System.Math.PI * 3.0 / 2.0;
            }
            else if (pyRes == 0.0)
            {
                if (pxRes > 0.0)
                    angle = 0.0;
                else
                    angle = System.Math.PI;
            }
            else
            {
                if (pxRes < 0.0)
                    angle = System.Math.Atan(pyRes / pxRes) + System.Math.PI;
                else if (pyRes < 0.0) angle = System.Math.Atan(pyRes / pxRes) + (2 * System.Math.PI);
                else
                    angle = System.Math.Atan(pyRes / pxRes);
            }
            // Convert to degrees
            angle = angle * 180 / System.Math.PI; return angle;

        }
```